# Transaction/Database Locking Scheme

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

If I am using JPA for ORM in a project, is whether optimistic or pessimistic locking is used a function of the JPA implementation, or is it a function of the database? In otherwords, if I'm using Hibernate as the JPA implementation, can I say whether or not to use optimistic vs. pessimistic locking, or is that baked into the implementation, or determined by the database, some combination of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your decision. JPA (and Hibernate) can do [both](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock).

Pessimistic via [EntityManager.lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#lock(java.lang.Object,%20javax.persistence.LockModeType)):

```
em.lock(employee, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

Optimistic via [`@Version`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Version.html).

Which one to choose depends on the application and the business case, not on JPA, JPA Implementation and the database.

Comment: The example you provided looks like you are individually adding a pesimistic write constraint on a single entity. Is there a way that you can apply the locking scheme on the entitymanager itself? That way, ALL operations would employ a certain locking scheme

Comment: @user1154644 This deserves another question. Your original question is answered.